# Python: why contents of list are different inside and outside function?

Tags: python, list, global-variables

I have a function doing binary tree traversal, and I have a global list "stack" to store temporary values.

```
stack = []

def search(root, v):
    global stack
    stack.append(root.info)    
    if root.info == v:
        print(stack) #<------- THE FIRST PRINT IS HERE
        return
    if root.left is not None:
        search(root.left, v)
    if root.right is not None:
        search(root.right, v)
    stack.pop()
    pass

def lca(root, v1, v2):
    search(root,v1)
    print(stack) #<------- THE SECOND PRINT IS HERE
```

Your Output (stdout)

```
[4, 2, 1]
[4]
```

[image: The tree]

input: v1=1, v2=7

When I print the value of the list from inside and outside the function, I found that the results are different -- when printed inside, the result is [4,2,1], and outside is [4]. I have tried different ways, such as creating the list outside the function, and then pass it to the function, the result is always the same. Can anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Could you precise your datas?
What are your tree's values?

To me, it seems like the stack.pop() is the source of your problem, you're retrieving the last element from the list at each iteration, but without even knowing your data structures and values it's difficult to answer.

Comment: Sometimes your `search` function prints `stack` and returns early. Sometimes it doesn't print, and gets all the way to the end of the function. Since `search` is recursive, multiple `search` calls are executed, some of which print `stack`, and some of which alter `stack` and don't print it. There's no reason to expect that the contents of `stack` when it gets printed are the same as the final contents.

Comment: You seem to believe that after you hit the `return` in your `search` function, your recursive search stops. But it doesn't. The `search` calls higher up the call stack will still go on triggering more searches, popping things off the `stack`, altering its contents.

Comment: @NyuB the tree will be like this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-assets/0/1527870675-1cfffe0a8a-LCASample.png)

Comment: And what is the value of v1?

Comment: @khelwood with the input v1=1, seems that the list [4,2,1] is correct. How can I ensure that I can get [4,2,1] outside the function?

Comment: @NyuB sorry for the confusion, v1=1

Answer (score 2):

You seem to believe that after you hit the explicit `return` in your `search` function, your recursive search stops. But it doesn't. The `search` calls higher up the call stack will still go on triggering more searches, popping things off `stack`, altering its contents.

Perhaps you want something like this: use a return value to signal from `search` when it has successfully found the thing it was looking for, and don't search any more after that happens.

```
def search(root, v):
    global stack
    stack.append(root.info)    
    if root.info == v:
        print(stack)
        return True
    if root.left is not None and search(root.left, v):
        return True
    if root.right is not None and search(root.right, v):
        return True
    stack.pop()
    return False
```

This will prevent the stack being altered after the point where the value is found.

Comment: Thanks! enlightening!